# Unknown Number of User Inputs. Inputs Being .xlsx Files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a simple code that does some analysis on .xlsx files. These files are converted to pandas dataframes then modified and plotted. The problem I am having is that I don't know how many files of interest there will be each time the program is run.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Prompt user to enter in Files
data=list()
while true:
    file=input('Enter .xlsx File Name/nType 'Done' When Complete')
    if file == 'Done': break
    else:
        data.append(pd.read_excel(file))


#Crunch Data 
def somefun(data[i],..):
    return list a
def anotherfunc(data[i],..):
    return list b

#plot Data....
```

Here I am converting each file to a dataframe then appending it to a list. I think I can proceed this way but it might not be 'pythonic'. I have only recently begun to use object oriented programming. Sounds like I could create instances of an object from each user interface by defining my own class. I am having trouble thinking about how to construct the class and if that is more work than it is worth.

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a script I use to iterate through all files of a certain type in a folder. I read each file into a dataframe, and then store the dataframe in a dictionary. A the end, you can just concatenate all the dataframes into a single dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\project'

allfiles=os.listdir(path)
xlsx_list=[filename for filename in allfiles if filename[-5:] in [".xlsx"]]

ds = {}

for file in xlsx_list:
    ds[file] = pd.read_excel(path+'\\'+file)

df = pd.concat(ds)
```